# Javascript highlight/make text editable on focus

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a js fiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/YD6PL/99/

HTML:

```
<textarea id="txt-area1" readonly>a</textarea>
<textarea id="txt-area2" readonly>b</textarea>
<textarea id="txt-area3" readonly>c</textarea>
<textarea id="txt-area4" readonly>d</textarea>
<div>
<button class="buttons">á</button>
<button class="buttons">é</button>
<button class="buttons">í</button>
<button class="buttons">ó</button>
<button class="buttons">ú</button>
<button class="buttons">ñ</button>
<button class="buttons">ü</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('textarea').focus(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active')
    });

    $(".buttons").click(function () {
        var cntrl = $(this).html();
        $('textarea.active').append(cntrl);
    });
});
```

Is there a way that, upon focus on a text input box, I can also have the text automatically highlighted and ready to be edited (as opposed to having to select the text with the mouse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two new lines should work:

```
$('textarea').focus(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active')
    $(this).attr('readonly', false);   // make editable
    $(this).select();                  // select the text
});
```

Comment: `readonly` doesn't prevent you selecting text, just typing into it

Comment: @PaulS. Yes, but OP wants the boxes to become editable as well.

Comment: If they're editable when you click them then what's the point of readonly in the first place? The question isn't very clear..

Comment: pulled html from another example I was working on. Forgot to take out the readonly attribute!